# What is the unexpected symbol near then in these screenshots?

Tags: if-statement, lua, syntax-error, symbols

I'm using an android lua IDE program, and I can't seem to find the reason why it's giving me this error of "unexpected symbol near then" on line 27. please help it would be most appreciated[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcIsM.png

Comment: You have `if then then`. Is that legal in Lua? Remove the second `then`.

Comment: If i do that, it executes the first print command no matter what. I need it to be a conditional print command.

Comment: Also i just tried it and it still does the error. Its an unexpected symbol.

Comment: Please post your code within your original post surrounded within `code blocks` rather than a screenshot, it is more helpful for debugging.

Comment: Um sorry i am a beginner to lua, how exactly do i do the whole code block thing?

Comment: Indenting the code by 4 spaces will display it as code. You can also select and click on `{}`.

Comment: Again, i'm on a mobile device. That feature isnt available for touch devices.

Comment: You have a problem with your `if` conditions. 7 is considered true, therefore the whole expression is always true. Read up on [relational operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.4) and, just below that section, logical operators.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot:

```
if v == 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10
  then bal = subtract(bal,1000)
    then print("You lost the gamble! Your new balance is", bal")
elseif v == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 
  then bal = add(bal, 2000)
    then print("You won the gable! Your new balance is", bal)
end
```

Problem 1: every number is a true value, hence no matter what `v`'s value  is, `v== 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10` will always resolve to true.

You need to write `v == 6 or v == 7 or v == 8 or v == 9 or v == 10` or simply `v >= 6 and v <= 10`.

Same for `v == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5`.

Problem 2: the syntax of the conditional statement is `if condition then body end`. You cannot have extra `then`s.

Fixed code:

```
if v == 6 or v == 7 or v == 8 or v == 9 or v == 10 then
  bal = subtract(bal,1000)
  print("You lost the gamble! Your new balance is", bal")
elseif v == 1 or v == 2 or v == 3 or v == 4 or v == 5 then
  bal = add(bal, 2000)
  print("You won the gable! Your new balance is", bal)
end
```

Other issues:

Why would you have a subtract and add function? Replacing basic arithmetic operators with functions makes no sense. Just use `bal = bal - 1000`

As v seems to be an integer between 1 and 10, why not simply use `v < 6` as your win condition? The rest can be done with an else. You don't need to explicitly check every case.

Also your game doesn't make too much sense. Assuming you're using a uniform distribution in your random number generator you win 2000 half the games and lose 1000 half the games. So over many games you are guaranteed to win more than you lose.

Comment: This is the beginning of a win / lose gambling game. Thats the gamble 1000 system. I just needed help with that.

Answer (score 0):

A look in the Lua reference (I do not know the language):

```
if ...
    then
    do
        bal = subtract(bal, 1000)
        print("You lost")
    end
elseif ...
    then
        bal = add(bal, 2000)
        print("You won")
    do
    end
end
```

*(The indentation is probably entirely wrong.)*

Comment: This fixed the error, but now i'm losing every time. I think it might not be defined directly under the if else do statement, because lose is the one at the top and therefore has priority

Comment: actually you don't need `do end` in if statements.